# ChartJs different data for Tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My app consumes JSON which passes in a collection of datasets organized like this:

```
Date: "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
Percentage: 0.6667
Target: 0.01
Value: 1.51
```

I'm looping over the data and shoving Dates into an array.  Those become the labels (x-Axis)
I'm shoving Percentage into an array and those become the y-axis.
I want to use Value for the tooltip.

```
        _actual.push(dataIn[i].Value);
        _target.push(dataIn[i].Target)
        _percents.push(dataIn[i].Percentage * 100)

        _labels.push(dataIn[i].Date);
```

I was hoping I could just do something like:

```
 tooltips: {
                data: _actual
            },
```

but that doesn't work.

How can I bind a unique dataset to the tooltips?  I'm assuming I'll have to write a custom tooltip callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you could try:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {   
            let tooltip = ...;
            return tooltip;
        }
    },
    mode: 'nearest',
    intersect: false
},
```

Comment: Thank you @willystyle .  I was able to follow your suggestion and solve the tooltips like so: tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        let tooltip = _actual[tooltipItem.index];
                        return tooltip;
                    }
                }
            },                                                                                                                                                                                    where _actual is my array of values to bind to the tooltips.